# Is there any alternative to set_value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I am getting error as follows: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_value'".
The code is give here:

```
for i in range(0,len(text)):
   textB = TextBlob(text[i])
   sentiment = textB.sentiment.polarity
   new_df.set_value(i,'sentiment', sentiment)
   if sentiment < 0.00 :
       sentimentclass = 'Negative'
       new_df.set_value(i, 'sentimentclass', sentimentclass)
   elif sentiment > 0.00 :
       sentimentclass = 'Positive'
       new_df.set_value(i, 'sentimentclass', sentimentclass)
   else :
       sentimentclass = ' Neutral'
       new_df.set_value(i, 'sentimentclass', sentimentclass)
```

Answer (score 9):

`set_value()` was marked as [deprecated in 0.21](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html). The documentation says you can use [`at[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at).

```
df.at[row, column] = value
```

which should be

```
new_df.at[i, 'sentimentclass'] = sentimentclass
```

in your case

Comment: Thanks, I did it but still there's an error: unexpected indent

Comment: That's a normal Python mistake. Check the [indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) of your code.